# Form.io get JSON Data Component without submission?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, formio

In Form.io, I have the Data Component and this in the name of the input box write `data[FirstName]`. This is very hard to manage in a self programmed endpoint to save data on own server.

Is there is a way to get Data Component in JSON format for submit then in a ajax request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide relevant code.

Comment: Yeah, can you clarify your use case a little bit? I'm having trouble following